# Finding the expectation of n Poisson values in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, mean, poisson

> [image]

I have written the following code:

```
n <- 5
lambda <- 2
randomNumbers <- rpois(n, lambda)
prob <- dpois(randomNumbers, lambda)
```

Is my code correct thus far?

How can I find the expected values of 5 Poisson values?

```
eX <- mean(randomNumbers)
```

or,

```
weighted.mean(randomNumbers, prob)
```

Comment: The mean of a Poisson random variable is equal to lambda. Is there something missing in the question, is it supposed to be the total of the 5 numbers or something?

Comment: @Marius, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n <- 5
lambda <- 2
randomNumbers <- rpois(n, lambda)
# estimate of P(X = 0), for example
mean(randomNumbers == 0)
# estimate of E[X]
mean(randomNumbers)
```